# "Join this community" button is not really a button on Meta sites of beta sites

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites

Compare these two screenshots:

Beta site
[image]

Beta's meta site
[image]

In the latter it is hardly obvious that the "Join this community" is a button, unless you hover over it:
[image]

Then the colour becomes a tint darker, and shows some distinction from the background.

Can this button be re-styled, so that it is clearly a button on a Beta's meta site?

#### Some things that could be done to mediate this:

1. Add a shadow on all borders of the box, currently it has only a top shadow:

[image]

2. Seeing that the button uses a descripted colour, as pointed out by Peilonrayz in the comments, change the colour of the top bar, as that is a hardcoded HEX value `background-color: #242729;`. Changing that to `#262931` already provides a subtle difference:
   [image] compared against the original: [image]

Comment: The button is based of `--theme-primary-color`. I changed the value locally the other day as I found the voted arrows hard to distinguish from unvoted arrows, on the meta site I contribute most to (not a beta site).

Comment: [Here's an example](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/) if anyone wants to quickly test it for themselves.

Comment: I think that is just to show the dark-side of meta ....